# How to pass a variable into a schema in Scala

Tags: scala

I am creating a historic events table using data from a very large dataset that contains a user and their event states with timestamps when those states occur.

In order to do so, I am reading in the user state table with a specified schema, then looping through each row with a foreach statement, giving me a Seq[Object] which contains username, the event columns, and the time information.

Within this loop I am looping across an array of strings that contains the event columns I am interested in tracking for this project, like so:

```
case class schema(userID: String, Event: String, time:Timestamp)
val loopedcolumns = Array("Event") 
df.as[schema].take(10).foreach{
        rowName=>
            loopedColumns.foreach{
                colName =>
                    val newRow = List((rowName.userID, 
                        colName,                       // this contains the Event I want to track
                        rowName.colName,               // this contains the data in the event I want to track
                        rowName.time
    ))              
            }
    }
```

The issue I am running into is when I try to call the variable column name from my array of strings, the rowName.colName line, my code is unable to parse it as "the value inside colName" and instead as the literal string "colName" with the error:

`value colName is not a member of schema`

How do I go about passing in this variable into the schema so it reads it properly?

Comment: Please clarify, what is the `schema`? Does it have a field `colName` ?

Comment: `schema` has the fields: `userID`, `time`, and `event`, whose string value is currently contained in `colName`.

Comment: Could you add types to code snippet? What are `loopedColumns`, `schema`? From your code.

Comment: LoopedColumns is an array that contains the names of the columns I want to get information from. Schema is as mentioned previously.

Comment: You don't have `colName` field in your `schema` case class but `rowName` is `schema` object, and when you tried to get `rowName.colName` compiler tell you what schema doesn't have field `colName`

Comment: That is correct. I'm wondering if there is a way to pass in the information in colName so that it fetches the information I'm looking for.

Comment: you can do that only if you have `DataFrame` not `Dataset` of concrete case class object. And in this case you should know data types and get value from row using `row.getAs[{FieldType}]({fieldName})`

Comment: This was the solution. Thank you very much.